# Make a SQL query to find repeating message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a simple query and seems that I stuck here...
I have table with error log messages:

```
id | userID | errorCode | errorRef | date |  message
```

When I do some sequence of actions they all reference to same errorRef but with different errorCode.

I need to find all the users that experienced code "400" as a last error in sequence (by date) and got it in multiply sequences (more than 2).

For example, I should find userId = 1 if there are records like that:

```
1 | 1 | 333 | 127000 | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | pressed the Start
3 | 1 | 334 | 127001 | 2015-10-06 00:01:02 | click Cancel
2 | 1 | 400 | 127000 | 2015-10-06 00:00:01 | gets an error
3 | 1 | 333 | 127001 | 2015-10-06 00:01:01 | pressed the Start
3 | 1 | 335 | 127001 | 2015-10-06 00:01:02 | click Yes
3 | 1 | 400 | 127001 | 2015-10-06 00:01:03 | gets an error
3 | 1 | 333 | 127011 | 2015-10-06 00:01:01 | pressed the Start
3 | 1 | 336 | 127011 | 2015-10-06 00:01:02 | click No
3 | 1 | 400 | 127011 | 2015-10-06 00:01:03 | gets an error
```

I know it's simple query but I'm stuck for a long time with it.... Thanks

**Edit:** 
To make it more clear. I hope it will. There is a customer service software. And some customer service advisers do nothing after they got an error. They have to proceed with customer request processing. Some of them do, some of them don't. I need to find those who stop processing the request on this particular error more than twice. 
Sorry, didn't describe it first time.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: How is this different from just finding a user that has error 400 twice?  What does "in sequence" mean?

Comment: "400" can be not last message in sequence. Sequence is action within one order. Customer service software user creates an order (orderID = errorRef) and all the messages will be linked to it.

Comment: Maybe for you is clear, but for us isnt clear at all. You need spend more time to describe your problem. [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([id] int, [userID] int, [errorCode] int, [errorRef] int, [date] datetime, [message] varchar(17))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id], [userID], [errorCode], [errorRef], [date], [message])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 333, 127000, '2015-10-06 00:00:00', 'pressed the Start'),
    (3, 1, 334, 127001, '2015-10-06 00:01:02', 'click Cancel'),
    (2, 1, 400, 127000, '2015-10-06 00:00:01', 'gets an error'),
    (3, 1, 333, 127001, '2015-10-06 00:01:01', 'pressed the Start'),
    (3, 1, 335, 127001, '2015-10-06 00:01:02', 'click Yes'),
    (3, 1, 400, 127001, '2015-10-06 00:01:03', 'gets an error'),
    (3, 1, 333, 127011, '2015-10-06 00:01:01', 'pressed the Start'),
    (3, 1, 336, 127011, '2015-10-06 00:01:02', 'click No'),
    (3, 1, 400, 127011, '2015-10-06 00:01:03', 'gets an error'),
    (3, 2, 400, 127012, '2015-10-06 00:01:03', 'gets an error')
;

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID, ErrorRef ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RN
FROM Table1)
SELECT UserId 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1 AND ErrorCode = '400'
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I seemed to understand your requirements. You needed all users where the last known message within that order is an error 400, that have had at least 2 instances of this happening.

I added in an extra UserID just to show it works as expected.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I hope nobody loses their job because I gave you a solution ;)